# Laravel Belongs to many relationship response Error

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm working on my school Laravel Project. I have four models `User`,`Klass`,`course` and `School`
these are My Relations

```
User Model//
 public function teacherCourses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,'course_teachers','teacher_id','course_id');
}
public function klasses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Klass::class,'course_teachers','teacher_id','klass_id');
}
```

and

```
klass model//
public function teacherCourses(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class,'course_teachers','klass_id','course_id');
}
```

and

```
 Course Model//
    public function klasses(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Klass::class,'course_teachers','course_id','klass_id');
    }
```

My course_teachers table have `course_id`,`teacher_id`(user),`klass_id`,and `school_id`.

I want to return A teacher with his klasses and assigned courses inside the class.. how can i get that

**i have tried**

```
$user=User::with('klasses.teacherCourses')->where('id',$teacher->id)->first();
```

But I am getting the response with some extra data.. like the it  also return  other courses with having same classId (the course which is not assigned to the user).
how can i change this
is my relations are correct??

**note:** teachers can be assigned many classes and courses .. every relation is many to many i think

Comment: did set anything that it show the class is assigned

Answer (score 0):

Can you retrieve `klasses` and `teacherCourses` separately?

```
$user = User::with(['klasses', 'teacherCourses'])
    ->find($teacher->id);
```

or

```
$teacher->load('klasses', 'teacherCourses');
```

This way, additional `klasses` and `courses` will be associated with only one teacher, but you lost the relation between `klasses` and `courses`.